# Why isn't Babel working on my React Native project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I used react-native init and have reached a good point with my app, but now it's giving me serious issues with babel out of nowhere.

I got `Unexpected use of reserved word 'import'` went through steps:
 1. clear watchman watches.
 2. re-yarn all node modules
 3. reset Metro Bundler Cache
 4. Remove haste cache.

I've also deleted my `.babelrc` file because RN supposedly bundles the correct babel settings.

On Android emulator i get `unable to resolve module babel-polyfill`.

On Xcode / Simulator i also get `unable to resolve module babel-polyfill` from project's index.js

At my wit's end here. Tried uninstalling various incarnations of babel.

Versions: RN v0.55.4

i still have pkg json dev dependency of:

`"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.50.0"`

but i think thats default wrapped in RN so kind of moot.

What am i missing and is there a sane way of setting Babel for RN projects?

Comment: do you have `babel-polyfill` in your dependencies? and installed in your `node_modules`?

Answer (score 1):

yes it was an import of the babel polyfill, but do you know the explanation to this?

it is because you are writing ES6 code but import hasn't been yet totally added to it so polyfill transforms this to CommonJS, interesting isn't it? in the future it is predicted that you wont need it anymore since it will be implemented 100%

Comment: yeah, very familiar with the concept of babel. But it seems like there's 15 different packages to transpile your ES6, ES7 code now.

Hopefully as JS matures my debugging will get easier :P

Comment: they say webassembly is in line to take over JS in order to save us from pre-compiled hell so who knows if JS will have time to maturate (it possibly will tho)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being an import of the babelpolyfill module i'd left uncommented-out in the index.js file.

Totally ditzy by me.